# How to get last access time for the tables in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

At present we do have 500+ tables in Athena located under different databases. Currently we are planning to drop the tables which are not used for more than 120 days, for this purpose I am looking for an option to identify the last access time for each and every Athena table, so that I can use that info to take a decision whether to retain or drop the table.

As per the [boto3 glue](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue/client/get_table.html) doc, I tried retrieving LastAccessTime and LastAnalysedTime from boto3 glue client but the results are not reliable. Always getting default date for year set to 1970 and  am not getting any value for LastAnalysedTime.

Is there any other options to get the last access time for each table?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a couple of ideas:

- Check query history via API you will be able to retrieve the last 45 days of queries. You can process that and start having an idea of each table usage.
- Look this at S3 level. AWS S3 offers lot of tools for storage cost.
  One tool that can help you in that case is **Amazon S3 Storage Lens**. With this tool you can quickly see at S3 level which files has more usage than others.

> Amazon S3 Storage Lens is a cloud-storage analytics feature that you
> can use to gain organization-wide visibility into object-storage usage
> and activity.